# Unity 3D Platformer - Running Speed changing to controller stick input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After following a few guides, I made a controller that I like for my platformer game. What I need to figure out now is how to make the speed of the character adjust to how much input the control stick is being pushed on. (Minimal input = character walks vs. Max input = character runs) Here is what I have so far. I'm still pretty new to coding so I know the solution shouldn't be hard to figure out but I would still like some help on this. Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

static Animator anim;

public bool walking;

public GameObject playerModel;

//Transforms
public Transform playerCam, character, centerPoint;

private Vector3 moveDirection;

//character controller declaration
CharacterController player;

//Mouse Rotation
private float rotX, rotY;

//Mouse Y Position
public float mouseYPosition = 1f;

//Mouse Sensitivity
public float Sensitivity = 10f;

//Mouse Zoom
private float zoom;
public float zoomSpeed = 2;

//Clamping Zoom
public float zoomMin = -2f;
public float zoomMax = -10f;

public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

//Move Front Back left & Right
private float moveFB, moveLR;

//Movement Speed
public float Speed = 2f;

//Velocity of Gravity
public float verticalVelocity;

//Jump Distance
public float jumpDist = 5f;

//Multiple Jumps
int jumpTimes;

//To use with Dialogue Manager
public DialogueManager DiagM;

public AudioClip jumpSound;

AudioSource audioSource;


// Use this for initialization
void Start ()



{
    //character controller
    player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    //mouse zoom
    zoom = -3;

    centerPoint.transform.position = playerCam.transform.position;
    centerPoint.transform.parent = null;

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

}

// Update is called once per frame

void Update ()

{

    //if (DiagM.StartDialogue)
    //{ return; }

    //Mouse Zoom Input
    zoom += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomSpeed;
    if (zoom > zoomMin)
        zoom = zoomMin;
    if (zoom < zoomMax)
        zoom = zoomMax;

    //Mouse Camera Input
    playerCam.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, zoom);

    //Mouse Rotation

    rotX += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * Sensitivity;
    rotY -= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity;      

    //Clamp Camera

    rotY = Mathf.Clamp (rotY, -60f, 60f);
    playerCam.LookAt (centerPoint);
    centerPoint.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (rotY, rotX, 0);




    //Movement Speed

    moveDirection = (transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) + (transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized * Speed;
    moveDirection.y = verticalVelocity;

    player.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);



    //Movement Rotation

    centerPoint.position = new Vector3 (character.position.x, character.position.y + mouseYPosition, character.position.z);



    //Movement Input
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") != 0 || Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") != 0)

    {

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, centerPoint.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);          
        Quaternion turnAngle = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(moveDirection.x, 0f, moveDirection.z));
        playerModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (playerModel.transform.rotation, turnAngle, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

            anim.SetBool("isWalking",true);

    }
        else
    {
            anim.SetBool("isWalking",false);
    }  


    if (player.isGrounded == true)

    {
        jumpTimes = 0;
        verticalVelocity  = -Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    else

    {
        verticalVelocity += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (jumpTimes < 1)

    {
        //Jump Input
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"))
        {
            verticalVelocity += jumpDist;

            anim.SetTrigger("isJumping");

            audioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpSound, 1F);

            jumpTimes += 1;
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This line
    moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized * Speed;
Should change to this
    moveDirection = moveDirection * Speed;

normalizing a vector sets its length to 1. In your case you want its length to correspond to how far the joystick is pushed, so it shouldn't be normalized.